# Azure Resource Key RegEx

Tags: regex

Is there a way of writing a regular expression that will match to the sample: `G5CdMajvIpyyZ020VRddccTxkX/GjXjq5ID52+nrghg=`

but not match to the sample: `V2agTeXn6YXfUWhrDSJlVnwbrXMSRfCmi4rlrznOOEaG5CdMajvIpyyZ020VRddccTxkX/GjXjq5ID52+nrghg==`

The beginnings of an attempt: `[0-9A-Za-z\/\+]{43}=`, but this also matches a substring of the longer sample.

As you can see, they are similar strings.. i need to stop false positives on the later.

***Note***: If you didn't notice, the original string is exactly part of the second string.

Comment: Use anchors, `^[0-9A-Za-z\/+]{43}=$`

Comment: nice, so simple, my regex is bad 

Comment: hmm.. hold on, this doesn't seem to hit when they are on the same line..

Comment: Then use `\b[0-9A-Za-z\/+]{43}=`